# Force Log4J to create a new file every day (that may be empty)

Tags: java, log4j, rollingfileappender

I configured log4j to write use DailyRollingFileAppenders to write log-entries to some different files. 
One of these logs is special in that case, that it is a summary of all the other logs and its threshold is warn (not info like the others).

The idea behind this is simple: If there are no entries for a day, than everything is fine and there is no need to look at the detail-logs.

Log4J rolls that file when writing the first entry of the day - so if one opens that log and there was no entry written that day, the log will show days-old entries.

Is there a way to force log4j to roll a file every day **without the need of a log-entry**? Or alternatively to roll at startup?

Edit: Here are the properties:

```
**snipped**
log4j.appender.empty=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.empty.MaxBackups=30
log4j.appender.empty.Append=true
log4j.appender.empty.File=/some/dir/shouldBeEmpty.txt
log4j.appender.empty.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.empty.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%-15.15t] %-5p %-30.30c{1} - %m%n
**snipped**
```

Just to be sure: I know, I can just call a default-warn at nightly-startup and this will roll that file. But the question is, if it is possible to roll without logging.

Comment: can you give some example like i have a file.log when its 12:00AM it should move to file.log.1 or something of that sort?

Comment: You can always tell which day the entries are from by the file's last modified tag in the OS.

Comment: @almas shaikh - Sorry, what is missing? Can a DailyRollingFileAppender be forced to roll without the need to write a logentry? I will add the used properties.

Comment: @ Zoltán - Yes, you are right. And every entry has a timestamp. But the files are offered via http and that one is meant to be the first point of view for a non-developer to see if there is a problem with this server, so it should be that simple as 'empty log > OK'

Answer (score 1):

What you are searching for is the `CustodianDailyRollingFileAppender`.
This can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/my-pharmacy-project/source/browse/branches/perfum-proyect/src/java/logging/CustodianDailyRollingFileAppender.java?r=3).

Here is an example of the usage in an xml properties file:

```
<appender name="CDRFA" class="de.pickert.utils.logger.CustodianDailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="log/filename.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value ="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <param name="CompressBackups" value ="true"/>
    <!-- param name="MaxFileSize" value ="100mb"/>
    <param name="MaxNumbersOfDays" value ="14"/>
    <param name="DeleteFile" value ="false"/-->
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%p %C %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.SSS} %m \n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

**EDIT:**
Haven't seen that you want to create an empty file as well.
Maybe this helps:

*TimeBasedRollingPolicy*

specifies the use of a log filename that contains the current date. You do not need to specify a value for triggeringPolicy when you use this policy. To specify when a new log file is created, you can specify either of the following options:

- Creation of (rollover to) a new log file whenever the generated filename differs from the current filename. This is the default behavior.
  For example, if the filename includes the current year, month, and day, then a new file is created when the system date changes to a new day.
- Creation of a new log file only when a new session begins.
  When rollover occurs, the message Log continues in path-and-filename is written to the end of the current file. The message Log continued from path-and-filename is written to the beginning of the newly created file.

Use the following syntax to specify TimeBasedRollingPolicy:

```
<rollingPolicy class="TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <param name="fileNamePattern" value="filename-pattern"/>
    <param name="rollOver" value="TRUE | FALSE"/>
</rollingPolicy>
```

name="fileNamePattern" value="*path-and-filename-pattern*"
specifies the path to which the log file is written and the conversion pattern that is used to create the log filename. The conversion pattern can include the following characters:

**%d**
indicates where the current date appears. You can specify a date format or a date and time pattern in braces after %d if you want the date to appear in a format other than yyyymmdd, or if you want to include additional information such as the hour.

**%S{key}**
indicates where system information (such as the host name, operating system, or system description) appears. You must specify a key to indicate the type of system information that appears.

For example, specify c:\logs\MetadataServer_%d_%S{host_name}.log if you want the log files to be written to the path c:\logs\ and the filename to include the current date and the name of the metadata server host machine.

**Default:**    None
**Required:**   Yes
**Interaction:**    path and filename is overwritten by any value that you specify for path-and-filename.

name="rollOver" value="TRUE | FALSE"
indicates whether a new log file is created whenever the generated filename differs from the current filename. Specify one of the following values:

**TRUE**
creates (rolls over to) a new file whenever the generated filename differs from the current filename.

```
Quit not sure if this fits your needs
```

**FALSE**
creates a new log file only when a new session begins.

**Default:**    TRUE
**Required:**   No

[source](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/logug/61514/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003198579.htm)

Comment: I found a system-info-log, that was made anyway every-day. I made this a warning now and because of the server starting new every morning, this will fit my needs as long as there is this restart.  
I will try, when the server won't restarts every night. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the log4j configuration from code using two simple class [java.util.Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)  and [org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html). So at first load the whole log4j data (what you have provied with the question) in the java.util.Properties and then set it in `org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator`. So what you can do, you can take the value from `log4j.appender.file.File` of your own.

Example:

```java
String fileName = "//some//dir//" + {DD_MM_YY} + ".txt";`
log4jData += "log4j.appender.empty.File=" + fileName;`
```

Now, if you can set it once by your code, you can set it as many times as you want. Create a worker which will be responsible of two things:

1. if the application starts/restarts then set the desired log4j properties and
2. Configure the new log4j properties (based on your data) after a certain period (like 24 hours).

Hopefully, it will work. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Thanks. Your English is good enough, I always have the same problem when writing questions :-). Ok. Your solution is the hard(coded) way. If this really is the only solution, than I'll prefer to log a dummy-warning at startup and let log4j do this. I hoped there would be a simple 'switch' I over-read in the docs.

Comment: Yes, this is a solution using code and it might not be the best/preferable one. Hope that, you will find a better solution using log4j functions (not using hard coding). Best of luck.